# multi-user communication

Tags: digital-communications

For a multi-user communication, I do many signals $s_i(t)$ with $i \in \{1,...,N \}$, $N$ the user number. The bandwith for each $s_i(t)$ is the same.

But when I do the Fourier transform of $s_i(t)$, $FT(s_i(t))=S_i(\nu)$. The $S_i(\nu)$ are not centered in the same place. For example $S_1(\nu)$ is centered at $1$ Hz and $S_3(\nu)$ is centered at $10$ Hz.

Here is my question:
In digital communication, can we transmit signals simultaneously (multi-user communication) whose fourier transforms are not centered at the same point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Multiple users can communicate simultaneously on different carrier frequencies. FDMA